# Theorem about a continuous function that does not have global minimum at (a,b)

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima, extremal-combinatorics, analytic-continuation

Theorem:

If $f(x)$, which is continuous and non-constant on $(a,b)$, does not have a global minimum in $(a,b)$ then if the limits exist we have :

$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) < f(y)$ for every $a<y<b$, or
$\lim_{x\to b} f(x) < f(y)$ for every $a<y<b$.

The theorem seems easy to understand but extremely difficult to prove.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is statement (1)?

Comment: I guess you mean $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) < f(y)$ for all $y \in (a, b)$, right? Having $x$ as a dummy variable for the limit as well as a variable ranging over $(a, b)$ is confusing!

Comment: I made some changes in the form of the question.  Does it make sense now?

Comment: Good edits! I think it's much clearer now. However, I am not sure that these hypotheses are actually enough to guarantee these limits exist - consider a function like $(1 - x)\sin(1/x)$ on $(0, 1)$. Is this question from somewhere, or a lemma you came up with yourself? Have you included all the context? Perhaps we should assume that the limits exist, or you meant to state it in terms of $\limsup$ - in which case I think it's probably still true, actually.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen This is a lemma that I came up with myself trying to solve a problem. With what you said, i think that it would be wrong not to mention that the limit exists. So I am making an edit to the initial question.

Comment: OK, great. One to argue about this is to note that $f$ extends continuously to $[a, b]$, and by the Extreme Value Theorem, one of $a$ and $b$ must be a global minimum. The answer below essentially proves this theorem. To argue that it's still true for $\limsup$'s, you can suppose not: $f(y_1) \le \limsup_{x \to a} f(x)$ and $f(y_2) \le \limsup_{x \to b} f(x)$, choose $y_i'$ with $f(y_i') < f(y_i)$, and then choose $\varepsilon$ st $f > \min_i f(y_i')$ within $\varepsilon$ of $a$ and $b$, and then apply EVT on $[a + \varepsilon, b - \varepsilon]$ to find a global minimum.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen It does not work with $\limsup$. Take $f(x) = - \frac{1}{x}\sin^2(\frac{1}{x})$ on $(0, 1/\pi)$. Both limsups are $0$ but $f$ is non positive.

Comment: @Gribouillis, good point of course!!! I meant $\liminf$... I'm ill at the moment. Apologies.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is take a minimizing sequence, that is to say a sequence $x_n\in (a, b)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = \inf_{x\in (a,b)} f(x)
\end{equation}
The condition on $f$ not having a global minimum implies that $x_n$ cannot have a limit point in $(a,b)$. Hence the only possible limit points of $x_n$ are $a$ and $b$. Upon extracting a subsequence you can conclude that there exists a minimizing sequence converging either to $a$ or $b$.

You can also summarize this in the following equality
\begin{equation}
\inf_{x\in(a,b)}f(x) = 
\min(\liminf_{x\to a^+} f(x), \liminf_{x\to b^-}f(x))
\end{equation}